# Объединить несколько запросов к БД через LiveData

Tags: android, livedata

Как можно с помощью `LiveData` во `VideModel` (`Repository`) обработать два запроса в БД и вернуть совместный результат? Например, получить `id` из `UI` передать его во `ViewModel`, и запросить из разных таблиц данные, дождаться, когда все данные будут готовы (из двух запросов), только после этого вернуть `LiveData` (может `Map` или другую структуру).

```
val userId = 1001
userDao.getById(1001)
photoDao.getPhotosByUserId(1001)
```

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/534-urok-10-room-zapros-iz-neskolkih-tablic-relation.html

Comment: @pavlofff т.е. предлагаете сделать класс, который содержит связи которые нужно? Это одно из решений, которое позволит так сделать. А объединить именно существующие запросы без объединения, более абстрактное?

Comment: Есть как бы определенные законы работы реляционных баз данных, целая наука СУБД, стоит придерживаться их, а не изобретать собственный неведомый путь или идти уже им в гордом одиночестве, не спрашивая, как мне все сделать неправильно

Comment: можно использовать внутренний флаг-статус процесса. например Int'овую переменную.
в начале запроса она ==0. по мере прихода каждого ответа вы ее увеличивается +1.
когда она достигает нужного значения (кол-во запросов из БД) - вы все нужные данные записываете в LiveData.
и сбрасываете флаг опять в нуль.